# how to compile javascript package to windows installable exe or appimage

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, electron-builder, electron-packager

hello i am trying to compile a opensource project called skybrush live https://github.com/skybrush-io/live to windows installable they used "npm start" and "npm run start:electron" to launch the application, but i need to compile the whole project to a installable package

i tried "electron-builder -p never --win" to compile and also pkg command, it shows app entry point not found and launcher.bundle.js not found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.